# ragged2e: "newcommands" option produces "underfull \hbox" warnings

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, hyphenation, warnings, ragged2e

The [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package provides the commands `\Centering`, `\RaggedRight` and `\RaggedLeft` for setting ragged text while allowing hyphenation. The package offers a `newcommands` option that sets the standard LaTeX commands `\centering`, `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` equal to their `ragged2e` counterparts. However, when using this option, I've stumbled upon two instances where LaTeX will produce `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` warnings:

- Creating a title with `\maketitle`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

  \begin{document}

  \author{Author}
  \title{Title}
  \maketitle

  \end{document}
  ```
- Creating headers and footers with either the `fancyhdr` or the `scrpage2` package:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{blindtext}

  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}

  \begin{document}

  \blinddocument

  \end{document}
  ```

What causes these warnings, and what are proper ways to remove them?

EDIT: In response to Herbert's answer: I'm looking for a solution that keeps hyphenation while getting rid of warnings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to p. 4 of the `ragged2e` documentation (thanks to Herbert for encouraging me to RTFM), the `ragged2e` lengths which control `\leftskip` resp. `\rightskip` for `\Centering` & friends *"must be set to a finite value, to make hyphenation possible"*. (By default, `ragged2e` uses a value of `0pt plus 2em` instead of standard LaTeX's `0pt plus 1fil`.) But finit glue in turn means that "underfull `\hbox`" warnings become possible. In practice, such warnings are likely to be issued for one-liner or two-liner paragraphs typeset with `\Centering` & friends in effect -- i.e., they will turn up in (but are not confined to) title pages and headers.

This is demonstrated in the following MWE, which typesets text within three `center` environments (which, because `ragged2e`'s `newcommands` option is enabled, internally use `\Centering`). The first environment will produce an underfull `\hbox` with a badness of 10000, the second environment one with a badness of 4096. In the third environment, the sixth word is moved to the second line (instead of being hyphenated), and no warning is issued.

To remove all those "underfull `\hbox`" warnings, `\hbadness` may be set to a value of 10000 for `\Centering` & friends (again thanks to Herbert for the tip). Note that, if the `newcommands` option is enabled, one must add `\hbadness=10000\relax` (EDIT: or, even better, `\hbadness=\@M`) to the new definitions of, e.g., `\centering` as well as to the start of `center` environments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

% Uncommenting the following lines will remove "underfull \hbox" warnings
\makeatletter
% \g@addto@macro{\centering}{\hbadness=\@M}
% \g@addto@macro{\raggedright}{\hbadness=\@M}
% \g@addto@macro{\raggedleft}{\hbadness=\@M}
% \g@addto@macro{\center}{\hbadness=\@M}
% \g@addto@macro{\flushleft}{\hbadness=\@M}
% \g@addto@macro{\flushright}{\hbadness=\@M}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
hyphenation
\end{center}

\begin{center}
hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation
hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation
\end{center}

\begin{center}
hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation
hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation hyphenation
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you can omit `\relax` if you use `\@M` instead of `10000`.

Answer (score 5):

With `ragged2e` you have `\CenteringRightskip=0pt plus 2em`, but LaTeX uses
a value of `0pt plus 1fil`. You can set  `\CenteringRightskip` to this value and there will be no warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose that `\CenteringLeftSkip` should also be corrected. Also, your suggestion will remove hyphenation from `\Centering`, and I'd like to keep hyphenation while getting rid of warnings (if possible).

Comment: @lockstep: `{\hbadness=10000\maketitle}` and read the documentation on page 4.

Comment: Okay, so `plus 1fil` will kill hyphenation. Also thanks for the idea to set `\hbadness` to 10000 locally. Still, it's treating the symptom, and I'd like to know the cause.

Comment: it is explained in the documentation of ragged2e

Answer (score 1):

I recommend loading the ragged2e package with the default `originalcommands` option instead of the `newcommands` option and only modify selected parts of the document (sections, captions, …) to be `\RaggedRight`. In multi-line text, "Underfull `\hbox`" warnings are rare. You usually should not use hyphenation on the title page and you should not need it in headers and footers anyway.

In my opinion, `\RaggedRight` is only useful for typesetting multi-line narrow text or multi-line text containing many non-breakable sequences such as URLs. This applies to captions, e.g. through the `justification = RaggedRight` option for package `caption`. In these cases, `0pt plus 2em` might not be enough, so I'd increase this limit a bit, e.g. setting it to `0pt plus 3em`.

Note that with @lockstep's answer, when uncommenting the lines between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, every horizontal badness will be silenced. Since there might be valid reasons for these warnings, you should not silence them. With the original parameters, at least "Overfull `\hbox`" warnings will still be shown.